# I'm searching for a way to add a minimum shipping fee to a Shopping Cart Price Rule

Tags: shipping, magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping

I'm searching for a way to add a minimum shipping fee to a Shopping Cart Price Rule. 
I've set up free shipping for most items in the store. For heavy and truck freight items, they are excluded.
 I have the rule working just as I want. However, when all items in the cart qualify for free shipping, I want there to be a $5 minimum charge for handling.
 I have not yet found a solution for this. Discounts yes, adding a fee through the rules, no. I have searched for solutions and for extensions to do this but come up empty. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: screen grab of shopping cart rule]